# subprocess, returned non-zero exit status 1

Tags: python, bash

Такой код:

```
import re
import subprocess
import random
pas = ''
for x in range(3): #Количество символов (3)
    pas = pas + random.choice(list('1234567890')) # Генерация случайного числа.
cmd = str(subprocess.check_output([f'ping', '-c {pas}', 'google.com'], text=True))
print(type(cmd)) # Печатает тип переменной
print(cmd)
```

Пишет ошибку:

```
ping: invalid argument: ' {pas}'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/kali/test.py", line 13, in <module>
    cmd = str(subprocess.check_output([f'ping', '-c {pas}', 'google.com'], text=True))
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 466, in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.11/subprocess.py", line 571, in run
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['ping', '-c {pas}', 'google.com']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
```

Кто может написать валидный код?

Comment: Ошибка говорит сама за себя: `ping: invalid argument: ' {pas}'` Вы передаете пингу не значение переменной 'pas' а строку '{pas}'.

Answer (score 1):

Обработайте ошибку чтобы увидеть опечатку:

```
import subprocess
import random


pas = random.randrange(1, 10)

try:
    output = subprocess.check_output(['ping', '-c', f'{pas}', 'google.com'], text=True)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    print(repr(e))
    output = e.output

print(output)
```

> ```
> $ python temp.py
> PING google.com (173.194.222.101) 56(84) bytes of data.
> 64 bytes from lo-in-f101.1e100.net (173.194.222.101): icmp_seq=1 ttl=108 time=4.54 ms
> 64 bytes from lo-in-f101.1e100.net (173.194.222.101): icmp_seq=2 ttl=108 time=4.62 ms
> 64 bytes from lo-in-f101.1e100.net (173.194.222.101): icmp_seq=3 ttl=108 time=4.63 ms
> 64 bytes from lo-in-f101.1e100.net (173.194.222.101): icmp_seq=4 ttl=108 time=4.61 ms
> 64 bytes from lo-in-f101.1e100.net (173.194.222.101): icmp_seq=5 ttl=108 time=4.59 ms
> 64 bytes from lo-in-f101.1e100.net (173.194.222.101): icmp_seq=6 ttl=108 time=4.64 ms
> 64 bytes from lo-in-f101.1e100.net (173.194.222.101): icmp_seq=7 ttl=108 time=4.62 ms
> 64 bytes from lo-in-f101.1e100.net (173.194.222.101): icmp_seq=8 ttl=108 time=4.59 ms
>
> --- google.com ping statistics ---
> 8 packets transmitted, 8 received, 0% packet loss, time 7011ms
> rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 4.549/4.610/4.646/0.044 ms
> ```